# Who is credited with inventing the term "high dimensional data"?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, terminology, high-dimensional, history

Title says it all, who is credited with inventing the term "high dimensional data"?

Comment: I know that the term pre-dates the 1980's.  It has also drifted in scope in that what was "high" in 1970 is somewhat different than what is "high" in 2016.

Comment: It's such an obvious term that I'd be surprised if any one person is collectively considered (as in already in people's minds) to have credit for it, but if anyone does, I'd suspect the action of Stigler's Law and not put much weight on it. So much is credited to the wrong person as it is.

Comment: In terms of public perception, the fourth dimension became a craze that inspired Picasso and others at the beginning of the 20$^{th}$ century as, I think, influenced by Einstein. The mathematical concept of more that 3 dimensions is a lot older than that, of course.

Answer (score 2):

I tried looking in Google Books high dimensional. Before 1970, I didn't noticed the term in the context of data but I might have missed some references.

I found the 1973 book "[A Method for the Selection of Variables for Classification of High-dimensional Data](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=2K1GAAAAIAAJ&q=%22high%20dimensional%22&dq=%22high%20dimensional%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y)" by [Larry Randolph Muenz](https://statistics.stanford.edu/people/larry-randolph-muenz) from Department of Statistics, Stanford University. It was Muenz's dissertation.

So, it might not be the first occurrence but for sure the term was used by 1973.

Comment: My apologies, but I find this question a bit silly. Consider a room. At each Cartesian point, there is a temperature, an atmospheric pressure, and air current 3-D vector, a dust content density, an electrostatic charge, a gravitational pull in a 3-D direction, a gravitational gradient, a Coriolis force, a local speed of light, and on and on as limited only by what we wish to measure. So, how many times have combinations of such things been considered, and when was the first time?

Comment: I think that the focus of the question is about the history of the terminology, not about research in high dimensions. Though I'm not an historian, I believe that in the past the ability to cope with high dimensions was lower to the computational effort. Fisher choose to use 4 features in the Iris data set though he probably could obtain some more.

Comment: Although [the notion of higher dimensions goes back to René Descartes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension), substantial development of a higher-dimensional geometry only began in the 19th century, via the work of Arthur Cayley, William Rowan Hamilton, Ludwig Schläfli and Bernhard Riemann. Riemann's 1854 Habilitationsschrift, Schläfli's 1852 Theorie der vielfachen Kontinuität, Hamilton's 1843 discovery of the quaternions and the construction of the Cayley algebra marked the beginning of higher-dimensional geometry.

Comment: *Exemplis gratis*, see [footnote page 224 circa July 1893](http://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~julie.deserti/biblio/Klein_AComparativeReviewOfRecentResearchesInGeometry.pdf) referring to earlier work by the same author.

Comment: You are most welcome. If you think it useful, I can collate, elaborate and include comments as an answer. I would hesitate to do so without support from discerning readers such as yourself.

Comment: I saw you added an elaborated answer. Good for us ;-)

Comment: Indeed, and thank-you for your kind remarks, I'm touched :)

Answer (score 2):

Q: Who invented the term "high dimensional data."

First of all, visualization of higher dimensional data, and models, was developed mathematically in the French language and developed in German. The notion of higher dimensions goes back to [René Descartes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension#In_mathematics), substantial development of a higher-dimensional geometry only began in the 19th century, via the work of Arthur Cayley, William Rowan Hamilton, Ludwig Schläfli and Bernhard Riemann. Riemann's 1854 Habilitationsschrift, Schläfli's 1852 Theorie der vielfachen Kontinuität, Hamilton's 1843 discovery of the quaternions and the construction of the Cayley algebra marked the beginning of higher-dimensional geometry. *Exemplis gratis*, see [footnote page 224 circa July 1893](http://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~julie.deserti/biblio/Klein_AComparativeReviewOfRecentResearchesInGeometry.pdf) referring to earlier work by the same author in German.

With the development of [special relativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annus_Mirabilis_Papers#Special_relativity) in 1905 by Albert Einstein, it was shown that only [4D spacetime $(x,y,z,t)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacetime) is invariant, not 3D space $(x,y,z)$. This hit the public's imagination like a mindfire. Einstein’s four-dimensional universe, is conceptually different from four spatial dimensions. But the two kinds of four-dimensional world became [conflated in interpreting the new art of the 20th century](https://www.britannica.com/science/relativity/Intellectual-and-cultural-impact-of-relativity). Early Cubist works by Pablo Picasso that simultaneously portrayed all sides of their subjects became connected with the idea of higher dimensions in space, which some writers attempted to relate to relativity.

The first person to add a fifth dimension to a theory of gravity was [Gunnar Nordström in 1914](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_theory#Early_results), who noted that gravity in five dimensions describes both gravity and electromagnetism in four. Nordström attempted to unify electromagnetism with his theory of gravitation, which was however superseded by Einstein's general relativity in 1919. Thereafter, German mathematician Theodor Kaluza combined the fifth dimension with general relativity, and only Kaluza is usually credited with the idea. In 1926, the Swedish physicist Oskar Klein gave a physical interpretation of the unobservable extra dimension—it is wrapped into a small circle. Einstein introduced a non-symmetric metric tensor, while much later Brans and Dicke added a scalar component to gravity. These ideas would be revived within string theory, where they are demanded by consistency conditions. [One notable feature of string theories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_theory#Extra_dimensions) is that these theories require extra dimensions of spacetime for their mathematical consistency. In bosonic string theory, spacetime is 26-dimensional, while superstring theory is 10-dimensional and supergravity theory 11-dimensional. In order to describe real physical phenomena using string theory, one must therefore imagine scenarios in which these extra dimensions would not be observed in experiments.

Finally, although one can ascribe sign posts to past events, I agree with @Glen_b that [Stigler's Law of eponymy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stigler's_law_of_eponymy), which given the chicken and egg phylogeny of an onion layered dialectal term, prohibits isolation of an ontological moment for origin of a thought. That is, there was never a first egg, or a first chicken, there was a continuum of proto-chickens that species drifted to become modern chicken. Likewise, higher dimensionality is something we understand without being told, we avoid future events when we avoid getting hit by a bus (4D spacetime), or put a coat on when it is cold out (5D spacetime + temperature).

In statistics, it is hard to say when multi-dimensionality first occurred. For example, [Mahalanobis n-space distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahalanobis_distance) dates from 1936. However, Euclidean $n$-space distance (or Hilbert space distance) is just [root sum squared](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_space#Distance), so that it has been around at least as long as a standard deviation.

As lessons in humility, when Newton was asked how it came to be that he conceived of so much, he reputedly responded that "If I have seen further, it is by standing on the shoulders of giants."  That thought (Latin: *nanos gigantum humeris insidentes*) is in turn attributed to Bernard of Chartres in the 12$^{th}$ century. When Einstein was asked how he came to be such a genius, he responded, "It's not that I am so smart. I just stay with problems longer." And one has to, to develop a dialectic.

Comment: Wasn't Hilbert space an important mathematical development in extending theory from simple Euclidean space? Among Hilbert's students was John von Neumann ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Hilbert

Comment: @DJohnson Indeed, Hilbert space admits an infinite number of dimensions. I did not leave him out on purpose, I just do not know everything about such a broad concept as dimensionality. For example, in machine learning, I did not know about the [curse of dimensionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimensionality) either.

Answer (score 0):

The word 'high' can be subject to much argument as to what exactly constitutes high.  However the term, the 'curse of dimensionality' is due to Bellman.  It refers to the fact that in large dimensional spaces problems exist that don't exist in low dimension.  The quintessential example would be, for me, the fact that most of the points of a sphere $S^n$ are concentrated around the edge and the proportion grows with n.  Once one believes in 'the curse of dimensionality' , high dimension, and hence high dimensional data would be data point in $\mathbb{R}^n $ for which this becomes an issue.

Comment: High is more than 3D in this context.